# res.json(), where is it responding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am new to the routing section and try to understand what's going on with this code , specially with res.json

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  db.find()
  .then(function(todos){
    res.json(todos);
  }
})
```

I need to know where this res.json is responding, is it to the frontend when they need it or is it for the database part? when we try to find all the info from the database using find() and then converting it into json, where is it going?

and the same for the POST route when we try to create a new Todo with create() we use res.json() again, here we are trying to post info to the server so why are we using res here?

Comment: the res.json is sent to the front end

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:mongoose] but the code you're asking about looks like [tag:express.js]. Some context to know what kind of object `router` actually is would help

Comment: router = express.Route();

Answer (score 2):

> **res.json([body])** Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter
>   converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().
>
> The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string,
>   Boolean, or number, and you can also use it to convert other values to
>   JSON, such as null, and undefined (although these are technically not
>   valid JSON).
>
> ```
> res.json(null);
> res.json({ user: 'tobi' });
> res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' });
> ```

source:
[res.json([body]) API from expressjs.com](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

According to your question this is helpful for frontend developer as response comes as a JSON Object for a GET request.

Be noted that res.json in create() method is used to return new created todo as a JSON to ease work for frontend developer.

In advanced Topics you will face Schema Validation which validates posted data from POST request but this data should be JSON to be able to validate it using Model Schema.

Comment: lets say for the POST route db.Todo.create(res.body).....here res.body would contain info coming from front-end which is parsed by body-parser. Now res.body object has the required info which we want to post. Now if using promises .then(function(newTodo){ res.json(newTodo); } where this res.json's newTodo will go, most probably to the server , right? so my question is why are we using res here as we are posting it to database. I am confused here. Please help me out

Comment: I got you now. this used to terminate request and response cycle. as we sent data to server using POST request then we need to terminate the cycle with a response, whatever we send data or just used res.json() only.
adding for that we can terminate request , response cycle with res.send() as well.
if we used app.post() only without sending any response then application will be hanged.

Answer (score 0):

`res.json()` will be sent to front-end

In your case,

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  db.find()
  .then(function(todos){
    res.json(todos);
  }
})
```

this will send a `data (todos)` returned from database

Answer (score -1):

The [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) can help with this, but in short, `res.json` takes the provided JSON, stringifies it, and sends it to the client (your browser, or whatever is making the web request)

Comment: "res.json takes the provided JSON" — It does not. JSON is the output, not the input.

Comment: Feel free to read the docs I linked in my answer. `res.json` doesn't return anything. JSON is the input

Comment: "Sends a JSON response" — The response is the output. (Note I said "output" and not "return value")

Comment: "The parameter can be any JSON type" — This is poorly expressed by the documentation. It means that it can be any JavaScript type that has a JSON equivalent.

Comment: I would argue your critique is pedantic to the point that it's confusing. The user asking the question is likely passing a JSON argument (as they are querying a database) and I would argue that in this case, an argument being passed to a function would constitute as an input, not an output

Comment: "passing a JSON argument" – No. They are likely to be passing an object (although they can pass an array, string, number, or other JavaScript data type with a JSON equivalent).

Comment: "an argument being passed to a function would constitute as an input" – Yes. It is. The function then converts it to JSON and sends it to the client. That (the JSON) is the output.

Comment: See also: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: My bad for the poor wording, technically it is a Javascript object but I think JSON and Javascript objects are pretty synonymous. This being said, I think that for a beginner trying to understand the basics of an HTTP JSON response, all of what you have posted is more likely to confuse than help him

Comment: "JSON and Javascript objects are pretty synonymous" — They are not.

Answer (score -3):

**res.body** won't contains info coming from front-end.

Info coming from front are in the **req** object (req=> request, res = response).

FrontEnd is asking for some data/action as said, all the data coming form FrontEnd is in the **req** object, after proceed you need to return a response (**res**) to your front.

It the same for **POST**, if server will have to perform an operation in DB, it will do it then notify the client **with the res.send() method**.

If you're confuse about POST and GET, so it seems you're not familiar with REST API. Let me write here a concise overview of that standard:

- http **GET** in order to get the data (from database or other source)
- http **POST** to create a new entry
- http **PUT** to update an existing data
- http **DELETE** to remove an entry

Take a look to that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) if you want more details.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question which asks what the different HTTP verbs are for. Your definitions of POST and PUT are very wrong.

Comment: You can modify wikipedia if you want

Comment: @shaykoo, am I right? you were confuse about get and post?

Comment: lets say for the POST route
db.Todo.create(res.body).....here res.body would contain info coming from front-end which is parsed by body-parser. Now res.body object has the required info which we want to post. Now if using promises 
.then(function(newTodo){
res.json(newTodo);
}
where this res.json's newTodo will go, most probably to the server , right?
so my question is why are we using res here as we are posting it to database. I am confused here. Please help me out

Comment: res.body won't contains info coming from front-end. Th info coming from front are in the req object (req=> request, _res_ = _response_). Since your Front is asking for some data or action to do all the data coming from front are in the req. after proceed you return a response (res) to your front. If client send a *POST*, seems server will have to perform an operation in DB. when that operation is done, it notify the client (with the res.send() method). Is it clear?

Comment: is there any platform where i can connect with you?

Comment: Is that answer your question? Or you're still don't understand how does it works?